# nvd3 lineplusBarChart add values from javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, bar-chart, nvd3.js

I have this code to produce a lineplusBarChart

HTML

```
<div id="chart1" class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'>
    <svg> </svg>
  </div>
```

Scripts

```
<script src="../lib/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="../nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="../src/models/linePlusBarChart.js"></script>
<script>
var time="1134345600000";
var quantity="12332212"

    var testdata = [
      {
        "key" : "Quantity" ,
        "bar": true,
        "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0] ]
      }
    ].map(function(series) {
      series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
      return series;
    });

testdata[0].values.push([time, quantity]);//NOT SHOWING THE BAR
    var chart;

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
            .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
            .x(function(d,i) { return i })
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

        chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
          var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
          return dx ? d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx)) : '';
          })
          .showMaxMin(false);

        chart.y1Axis
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

        chart.y2Axis
            .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',.2f')(d) });

        chart.bars.forceY([0]).padData(false);
        //chart.lines.forceY([0]);

        d3.select('#chart1 svg')
            .datum(testdata)
          .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

        return chart;
    });

</script>
```

Now i want to add some variables to the graph from javascript. Let say i have two variables `var time="1134345600000"` and `var quantity="12332212"`. i want some how to push these two variables into `var testdata.values`.

Is there an possible way?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cKEqb/2/) (js code after line 23240)

Comment: `testdata.values.push(time), testdata.values.push(quantity);`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff doesnt working.  It throws an error: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Comment: Where exactly are you running that code, and where to you want to add the values?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I updated the post. I want to add the values to the graph

Comment: I still don't know where you're pushing those values. And why don't you add them to begin with?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff i want to push them in the testdata. Like the testdata would be `"key" : "Quantity" ,
        "bar": true,
        "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0],[1134345600000,12332212] ]` I dont add them in the begging because i generate through javascript and every time they are different

Comment: Where are you running the code I suggested?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff locally

Comment: I suggested some code for you to try. You said it didn't work. Where, in the source code you've posted, did you put it?

Comment: Right, it's actually an array because of the `.map` -- see http://jsfiddle.net/cKEqb/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff no errors now but it still not showing the bar with values `[1134345600000,12332212]`. It only shows the first `[ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0]`

Comment: For that you would need to push it like this http://jsfiddle.net/cKEqb/1/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff still nothing. Look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cKEqb/2/ . I have input all the js and css. Your code is in 23240 and then

Comment: Ok, this should do it -- http://jsfiddle.net/cKEqb/3/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff This works perfect. Please post it as an answer so that i can to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, you need to push the data like this:

```
testdata[0].values.push({x: +time, y: +quantity});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cKEqb/3/).